# Flink - Failed to get metadata for topics exception while consuming from kafka topic

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have setup flink operator and kafka on minikube (both are on different namespaces). I am trying to consume messages from a kafka topic in flink and do some transformations. I am able to publish messages to the topic with sample java code, with below properties:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9094");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
```

I'm using `localhost:9094` because I did `minikube tunnel` and this is working. For flink I'm doing port forwarding, so that I can execute the code with `localhost:8081` and I'm able to execute example WordCount jobs. In flink, I'm trying to consume messages like this:

```
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9094")
        .setTopics("input_topic")
        .setGroupId("test_group")
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
        .build();

DataStream<String> stream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Source");
```

However, I'm not able to execute this code, as the flink job is throwing exceptions:

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Global failure triggered by OperatorCoordinator for 'Source: Entity Source -> Sink: Print to Std. Out' (operator cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2).
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.OperatorCoordinatorHolder$LazyInitializedCoordinatorContext.failJob(OperatorCoordinatorHolder.java:545)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.coordination.RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator$QuiesceableContext.failJob(RecreateOnResetOperatorCoordinator.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.failJob(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:287)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.SourceCoordinatorContext.handleUncaughtExceptionFromAsyncCall(SourceCoordinatorContext.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Failed to list subscribed topic partitions due to 
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.checkPartitionChanges(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:237)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$null$1(ExecutorNotifier.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ThrowableCatchingRunnable.run(ThrowableCatchingRunnable.java:40)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get metadata for topics [input_topic].
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.TopicListSubscriber.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(TopicListSubscriber.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.KafkaSourceEnumerator.getSubscribedTopicPartitions(KafkaSourceEnumerator.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.source.coordinator.ExecutorNotifier.lambda$notifyReadyAsync$2(ExecutorNotifier.java:80)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeTopics
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.subscriber.KafkaSubscriberUtils.getTopicMetadata(KafkaSubscriberUtils.java:44)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeTopics
```

Comment: 1) If the Flink code is running in k8s pods, you cannot use localhost, and tunneling is irrelevant 2) If you are running Flink on your host, make sure the Kafka pod is actually advertising `localhost:9094` as a valid address. You can use `kafka-console-consumer` to test with, too

Comment: I'm running Flink code in my local. I've tested kafka consume using command ```./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9094 --topic input-topic --from-beginning``` and I'm able to see the messages.

Comment: What is port 8081 for then? You've opened the Flink operator to "submit code" to k8s. Therefore it's running in the cluster, not on your host directly, and therefore localhost isn't referring to the Kafka broker or able to use the "tunnel". What other kafka addresses have you tried?

Comment: @OneCricketeer - port 8081 is for submitting flink jobs. Yes, I'm submitting code to k8s. When I grep for advertised listeners, I got this info ```advertised.listeners=CONTROLPLANE-9090://my-cluster-kafka-0.my-cluster-kafka-brokers.new-kafka-operator.svc:9090,REPLICATION-9091://my-cluster-kafka-0.my-cluster-kafka-brokers.new-kafka-operator.svc:9091,PLAIN-9092://my-cluster-kafka-0.my-cluster-kafka-brokers.new-kafka-operator.svc:9092,TLS-9093://my-cluster-kafka-0.my-cluster-kafka-brokers.new-kafka-operator.svc:9093,EXTERNAL-9094://127.0.0.1:9094```. I've tried the kafka-operator.svc as well.

Comment: That is for one particular pod, not any specific service that has gotten installed, but, since you have not given any TLS settings, try `.setBootstrapServers("my-cluster-kafka-0.my-cluster-kafka-brokers.new-kafka-operator.svc:9092")`

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I tried this, but it didn't work. It is resulting in same exception.

Comment: Alright, well, the PLAIN-9092 listener seems to be what you need. You also might need a network policy to access the resources across namespaces (try deploying in the same namespace first). And unclear what Kafka operator you're using, but a "headless" service address is what you should be attaching to rather than a numbered pod service address. Unless you explicitly need to use minikube, I'd suggest just running Kafka in Docker (Compose), then running Flink directly on your host to have direct access to your cpu and ram without limiting it by pod resource sizes

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I have re-deployed both into the same namespace few days back, still it errors out. I'm using strimzi kafka operator.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution or solve the metadata issue ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error when trying to use AWS Kinesis data analytics and trying to read from a Kafka topic in MSK. `Failed to get metadata for topics` I am providing the bootstrap servers with the TLS endpoint (port 9094)

Comment: Update - I was missing the VPC configuration, after adding it worked.